# Angular Redirection executes my method as well as NgOnInit. Why?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-local-storage, ngoninit

I am new with angular so bear with me.
I am having issue with Angular Redirection.When I clear storage manually, code executes ngOnInit, prompts error,redirects to Login page (as expected), but when I try to do same thing using logout method my code executes Logout Method, ngOnInit and then redirect to login page.
why it is executing ngOnInit of same page when I am redirecting to another page  ?
The code below shows logout method.

I tried making it globally, moving code to Constructor

```
this.localStorage.clear().subscribe(() => {
    console.log('Logout Method'); 
    alertify.success("Logout Successfull !!");  
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }, () => {
      alertify.error("Storage error"); 
});
```

The code should just execute logout method instead of executing both logout and ngOnInit

Comment: I am rusty with Angular, but I bet a reload is triggered when you clear local storage and that would trigger ngOnInit on the same page.

Comment: @Michelangelo but why this reload is getting triggered ? is it because of this.router.navigate(['URL']); function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I did some mistake in my code

`<a href="main_nav#" (click)="logout()" >Logout</a>`

I was directing my URL in **HREF** to main_nav and then calling logout().
So after removing contents of **HREF** it worked for me.

`<a href="" (click)="logout()" target="_self">Logout</a>`

This worked for me ☻

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you subscribe to localstorage method which executes same code again whenever observable emits event. So try this;

```
_onDestroy$ = new Subject<void>();
this.localStorage.clear()
.pipe(
takeUntil(this._onDestroy$))
.subscribe(() => {
    console.log('Logout Method'); 
    alertify.success("Logout Successfull !!");  
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    }, () => {
      alertify.error("Storage error"); 
});
ngOnDestroy() {
this._onDestroy$.next();
}
```

Comment: Still having the same issue getting two responses.